# Div's overlapping

Tags: html, css

So I have a forum and when the forum fills up enough, the 2 inner divs 'break through' the main white div. Any idea why? I just want them to be in each other with small 5px borders. This is my Css which shows what I'm trying to do.

Css

```
  #white {
      width:860px;
    height:auto;
    min-height:325px;
    margin-top:30px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
     margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
    position:relative;
    top:60px;
    background:rgba( 243, 243, 243, 0.7);
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px; 
  }

  #blue {
    background-color:#CDCDCD;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:830px;
    min-height:305px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:15px;
    background:rgba( 11, 185, 250, 0.8);
  }

  #grey {
    background-color:#292929;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 5px;
    width:820px;
    min-height:292px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    top:5px;
    background:rgba( 224, 224, 224, 0.8);
    padding-bottom:2px;
  }

  #container {
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 5px;
    width:795px;
    min-height:292px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    top:5px;
    font-size:17px;
    right:15px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add css on the main div

```
overflow:hidden
```

Comment: Ah yes! thank you! 4 Minutes til i can say u gave me the write answer x_x!